# Jupyter: How to execute cell magic placed in separate file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to have one file with some magic commands (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143753/ipython-notebooks-shortcut-for-run-all)) that I can call from multiple (not all) Jupyter Notebooks.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of. First, use the `get_ipython().run_cell_magic` command. For example you can put this in a `ipython_utils.py` module

```
def load_runall():
    get_ipython().run_cell_magic('javascript', '',
        """
        Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('r', {
            help : 'run all cells',
            help_index : 'zz',
            handler : function (event) {
                IPython.notebook.execute_all_cells();
                return false;
            }}
        );
        """)

load_runall()
```

And then simply run `import ipython_utils` in the cell of your notebook. A different approach would be to save to complete cell into a file and load it using the `%load` magic command and then run the cell normaly.

Comment: Option 1: Would you put all this in a file e.g. `jupyter_utils.py` file, and then in jupyter write `from jupyter_utils import *`, or how do you mean?

Comment: Yes, this is valid python code (when run inside ipython). I have adapted my answer.